# Relying Party - Unique Signing certificate condition in ADFS 2.1

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity, adfs, adfs2.1

I was trying to add two RP's (Relying Party ) in ADFS 2.1 for the same customer. They use the same signing certificate in both the applications. But while updating in Windows Server 2012 / ADFS 2.1  I am receiving the below error.

> MSIS7613: The signing certificate of the relying party trust is not
>   unique across all relying party trusts in AD FS configuration

This was a condition imposed on ADFS 2.0 and Rollup 3 fixed (rather subdued ) this issue. I thought ADFS 2.1 included the updates in Rollup 3. But surprisingly it did not.

This [post](http://emnavarro02.wordpress.com/2014/01/28/windows-server-2012-adfs-2-1-erro-msis7613the-signing-certificate-of-the-relying-party-trust-is-not-unique-across-all-relying-party-trusts-in-ad-fs-2-0-configuration/) (written in Portuguese) suggests a work around which looks a bit intricate. Is there any easier way to get around this error ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. Was solved by applying this hotfix:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2877424